# android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I am new in data binding and trying to bind recyclerview and getting following error. I am following a github repository.

> android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding
>   errors.data binding error 
>     msg:Cannot find the setter for
>   attribute 'app:data' with parameter type
>   java.util.List on
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.   file:D:\Android\All
>   Demo\TextAndImageSwitcher\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_list_data_binding.xml
>   loc:17:24 - 17:45 \ data binding error

view model file:

```
public class ListViewModel extends BaseObservable
{
    private Context context;
    public ListRecyclerAdapter listRecyclerAdapter;
    public List<User> userList;

    public ListViewModel(final Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        userList = new ArrayList<>();
        listRecyclerAdapter = new ListRecyclerAdapter(context, userList);
    }

    public void setUp()
    {
        populateData();
    }

    public void tearDown()
    {

    }

    @Bindable
    public List<User> getData()
    {
        return this.userList;
    }

    @Bindable
    public ListRecyclerAdapter getListRecyclerAdapter()
    {
        return this.listRecyclerAdapter;
    }

    private void populateData() {
        for (int i =0;i<=50;i++){
            userList.add(new User("Name("+i+")", "Mobile("+i+")", "Email("+i+")", "Address("+i+")"));
        }
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.data);

    }
}
```

my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="listViewModel"
            type="com.example.admin.textandimageswitcher.ListViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ListDataBindingActivity">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:adapter="@{listViewModel.listRecyclerAdapter}"
            app:data="@{listViewModel.userList}"
            android:id="@+id/list_data_binding_recycler">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Aren't you missusing ListView vs RecyclerView ? For RV you need to bind adapter (and set the data on it + notifyDataSetChanged) and layout for the rows. I'd also recommend to use `LivaData` instead of Observables.

Comment: Your information is incomplete, can you please show @BindingAdapter `app:data`?